# How to prove that in $Set$ the bijections are exactly the isomorphisms

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I want to prove in the category of sets that any function $f:X \to Y$ is bijective iff it has a retraction and a section.

It is easy enough to prove it one way, $\Leftarrow$, but to prove that $\Rightarrow$ holds as well is a little bit more difficult:

I know from on of the specific forms of the axiom of choice, i.e. $f$ is surjective implies split-surjective, that $f$ surjective implies $f$ has a section.

That $f$ has a retraction, is a little bit more difficult, since I need the domain of $f$ to be non-empty in this case. If $X$ is non-empty it follows that $f$ has a retraction, but what if $X$ is empty?

Any hints will be much appreciated!

Comment: If I understand well then you want to show that a bijection $f:X\to Y$ has a retraction and a section. But it seems quite evident to me that $f^{-1}$ serves as retraction and also as section for $f$. Am I missing something? Btw, if $f$ is a bijection with empty domain then also its codomain is empty.

Comment: I think you are right, but I am trying to prove it without assuming there is an inverse. Of course it can be constructed I guess, but I sort of want to see how general it is possible to give the proof, in categories in general. In order to see why $Set$ is different from other categories around.

Comment: What about showing that if $X \cong 0$ then $Y \cong 0$ since the isomorphism $0 \to X$ composed with $f$ is a morphism $0 \to Y$ and so $Y \cong 0$ in which case $f=1_0$ is the identity on $0$ and so has a retraction also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment suggests, if $f:X \to Y$ is bijective, we know that $f^{-1}:Y \to X$ exists. Check that this is a section and a retraction in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Or we can pretend we don't know set theory. Indeed, the axiom of choice translates to "every epi splits." I assume you've already shown that in $\mathbf{Set}$, an arrow is surjective just in case it's epic and an arrow is injective just in case it's monic. If not, you should show both these statements are true.

So we know that $f$ is a split epi and a mono. This is enough. Why? If $f$ splits, let $g: Y \to X$ be a section. $$fg = 1_Y \implies fgf = 1_Y \circ f = f = f \circ 1_X \implies gf = 1_X $$ where we use that $f$ is monic and $gf, 1_X$ are parallel arrows.